# How to write a class using a scanner to average digits of a number in Java

Tags: java

This is the shell I have:

```
import java.util.*;

//this example demonstrates how to to use a
//while loop to average all of the digits of a number

public class AveragingDigits
{
 public static int countDigits( int num )
 {
  return 0;
 }

 public static double sumDigits( int num )
 {
  return 0.0;
 }

 public static double averageDigits( int num )
 {
  return 0.0;
 }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
  Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );
  System.out.print( "Enter a number :: " );
  int num = kb.nextInt();
  System.out.println("The digit average is " + averageDigits( num) );
 }
}
```

How would I use this shell to print the average of the digits of a number that I input using the scanner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to do your method like this

```
public static int countDigits( int num )
{
    return (String.valueOf(num)).length();
}

public static double sumDigits( int num )
{
    double sum=0.0;
    while (num > 0) {
        sum += num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

public static double averageDigits( int num )
{
    return sumDigits(num) / countDigits(num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do it with your set up but it can be simpler with just one Calculate Average method.

```
    public class AveragingDigits
{
 int count=0;
 int sum=0;
 double temp=0;
double average=0;
double total=0;

 public static int countDigits( int num )
 {

 if (num==num)
{
 count++;

 }
 return count;
 }

public static double sumDigits( double num )
{

   temp=num;
total=total+temp;
return total;
 }

 public static double averageDigits( double num )
 {
 total=sumDigits( num );
 count=countDigits(  num );
 return total/count;
 }

 public static void main(String args[])
 {
 Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );
System.out.print( "Enter a number :: " );
 int num = kb.nextInt();
 System.out.println("The digit average is " + averageDigits( num) );
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    static String s = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number :: ");
        int num = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The digit average is " + averageDigits(num, 0, 0));
    }

    static double averageDigits(int number, int sum, int count) {
        if (number == 0) {
            if (count == 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ((double) sum) / ((double) count);
        } else {
            return averageDigits(number / 10, sum + number % 10, ++count);
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
Enter a number :: 12345
The digit average is 3.0
```